# Getting android_tutorial_pubsub connected to the roscore on PC (crash)

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to modify the android_tutorial_pubsub to let it connect to the roscore on computer so I can establish communications between them. I successfully build the tutorial and I am able to see the "Hello world n" on screen. However, the tutorial is building its own roscore in the phone by default, so I tried to find some solutions to modify it and I found a patch file.
([http://ias.in.tum.de/~moesenle/android_tutorial_pubsub.patch](http://ias.in.tum.de/%7Emoesenle/android_tutorial_pubsub.patch)).
After changing my code manually, it is compiled within eclipse IDE successfully. However, when the app launches on the phone, after I enter the http://localhost:11311/ and click OK, it crashes. It gives the following error in the log cat.
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1. I tried to debug the app but failed.
I hope that anyone could help me. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31367/getting-android_tutorial_pubsub-connected-to-the-roscore-on-pc-(crash)/) by [alexbeta20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2130/alexbeta20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use Lorenz's patch, then you need to actually start a master at the URI that you specify. If you're connecting to the roscore on a PC on the network, you need to put in that URI and not "localhost".

When I run Lorenz's patch with the URI set to localhost, it doesn't crash, but it also doesn't do anything. This is expected, since I'm not running a roscore on the tablet.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1